# Behave installation with Pydev

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev, python-behave

I'm new to Python. I would like to run Behave on an IDE.

So I'm trying to run the official tutorial of Behave.

When I run behave in a terminal command everything is OK. So I guess code/installation are OK !

[image]

Issues :

1 - I don't know why I still have those errors (Undefined variables given, when, then)

2 - 0 test executed when I do right click on step.py, "Run as Python unit-test"

3 - "no matching glue code" warning on my .feature file

[image: errors on exlipse]

Environment : Pydev and Cucumber plugins, Eclipse Neon, Jdk 8, Windows 10 64bits, Python 3.7.2 Behave 1.2.6

[image]

Comment: I've seen in youtube someone who does : "from behave import given,when,then". He's on an IDE and no issue... But I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was : "I want an IDE where I can execute Behave"

Pycharm do the job.

I made a script to execute tests easily :

cd /D %~dp0

behave

Comment: I have downloaded behave using pip install behave. My problem is I am not able to open feature file. I have also added behave plug in. I am using Pycharm Community edition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to integrate with an external runner, you can do it in PyDev too by using an external launch configuration (in the menu: `run > external tools`).

Another option for using it in PyDev, could be using a pytest with pytest-bdd to run it (to run pytest on PyDev you have to configure the runner in the `preferences > pydev > pyunit`).

Regarding imports not found, try adding `behave` to the `forced builtins` (see http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for instructions) and to avoid unused imports, import just what you want (`from behave import when, given, then`) or add a `#noqa` in that line.

Comment: How do i run behave based tests using pytest-bdd?  pytest-bdd has it's own completely different API and doesn't appear to support behave at all.

Comment: Eclipse -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Python Interpreter -> Forced Builtins -> New  (behave)